# is there any way in flutter in which we move to next screen without using ontap and pressed?

Tags: flutter-layout

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 200.0,
        width: 150.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: categoryModel.color, width: 4.0),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CategoryDetailScreen(categoryModel: categoryModel),
                    ),
                );
            },
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
                    categoryModel.name,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22.0),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Unstructured code! Also provide your use case

Comment: You may want to read [ask]